# Can a Magento API call mimic user facing search functionality?

Tags: ajax, magento, rest, search

When Magento renders search results after a user runs a keyword search, I'd like to fire an AJAX request that fetches the currently rendered products as JSON.

Currently, the extension JavasScript identifies product listings and parses some information into an object. For each object discovered, it then makes a call to the REST api to fetch the product in question:

```
/api/rest/products?filter[1][attribute]=name&filter[1][in]=<item name>
```

This works, since I don't have the product ID at the time I make the request, but isn't as efficient a process as I would like. Using the endpoint above with different filter parameters isn't reliably returning the same set of products, or even a collection that includes them.

Is there an API endpoint I haven't been able to find that leverages Magento's search logic? If not, how would I go about adding either a new endpoint or a new parameter that could re-use Magento's search logic?